# How do I disable Celery's default timeout for a task, and/or prevent it from retrying?

Tags: celery

I'm having some troubles with celery. Unfortunately the person who set it up isn't working here any more, and until now we've never had problems and thought we understood how it works well enough. Now it has become clear that we don't, and after hours of searching through documentation and other posts on here, I have to admit defeat. Hopefully, someone here can shed some light on what I am missing.

We're using several tasks, all of them are defined in a CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'runs-every-5-minutes': {
    'task': 'tasks.webhook',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),
    'args': (WEBHOOK_BASE + '/task/refillordernumberbuffer', {'refill_count': 1000})
    },
    'send-sameday-delivery-confirmation': {
    'task': 'tasks.webhook',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/2'),
    'args': (WEBHOOK_BASE + '/task/sendsamedaydeliveryconfirmation', {})
    },
    'send-customer-hotspot-notifications': {
    'task': 'tasks.webhook',
    'schedule': crontab(hour=9, minute=0),
    'args': (WEBHOOK_BASE + '/task/sendcustomerhotspotnotifications', {})
    },
}
```

That's not all of them, but they all work like this. All of those are actually PHP scripts that have no knowledge of the whole celery concept. They are just scripts that execute certain things, and send notifications if necessary. When they are done, they just spit out a JSON response that says *success=true*.

As far as I know, celery is only used to execute them periodically. We don't have problems with any of them except the last one from my code snippet. That task/script sends out emails, usually 5 to 10, but sometimes a lot more. And that's where the problems start, because (as far as I could examine by watching in `celery events`, I could honestly not find any confirmation for this in the docs anywhere) when the successful JSOn response from the PHP script doesn't arrive within 3 minutes, celery retries the task, and the script sends a lot of emails again. And again, because just a small amount of emails was saved as "done" form the tasks initial run. This often leads to 4 or 5 retries until finally enough emails were marked as "successfully sent" by the prior retries that finally the last retry finishes under this mystical 3 minute limit.

My questions:

1. Is there a default time limit? Where is it set? How do I override it? I've read about `time_limit` and `soft_time_limit`, but nothing I tried in the config seemed to help. If this is the solution, I would be in need of assistance as to how the settings are properly applied.
2. Can't I "just" disable the whole retry concept (for one task or for all, doesn't really matter) altogether? It seems to me that we don't need it, as we're running our tasks periodically and missing one due to a temporary error would not matter. I guess that means we shouldn't have used celery in the first place as we're misusing it, but for now I'd just like to understand it better.

Thanks for any help, and sorry if I left anything unclear – happy to answer any follow-up questions and provide more details if necessary.

The rest of the config file goes like this:

```
## Broker settings.
databases = parse_databases_xml()
settings  = parse_custom_settings_xml()

BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + databases['taskqueue']['host'] + '/' + databases['taskqueue']['dbname']

# List of modules to import when celery starts.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )

## Using the database to store task state and results.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_ANNOTATIONS = {
    "*": {"rate_limit": "100/m"},
    "ping": {"rate_limit": "100/m"},
}
```

There is no time_limit to be found anywhere, so I don't think we're setting it ourselves. I left out the python imports and the functions that read from our config xml files, as that stuff is all working fine and just concerns some database auth data.